# fitness benefits of different martial arts disciplines

Tags: martial-arts

What are the differences between different martial arts disciplines for various aspects of fitness (for example, flexibility, strength, endurance)?

Comment: I wonder if this would be better suited to http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/ or at least linked to over there so martial arts folks will come and answer.

Comment: This is such a broad question, it would be more useful to ask about a specific problem you are trying to solve and decide where the experts are. But asking what the *various* physical fitness benefits of between all the martial arts isn't going to be very productive in this type of Q&A.